# Always scanning for WiFi Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, scanning

Is there any way to create an app that always scans wifi and never stops checking. If so, does it not kills the battery quickly?
Can someone show me a good reference that scans for wifi and lists them in a listview?
I have tried this [Android Wi-Fi Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm) site but it doesn't work for me.

And this is what I do:

```
package com.example.amire.yadavar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private ListView lv;
    private WifiManager wifi;
    private WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        wifi.startScan();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }


    private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
            String[] wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

            for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
            }
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had found my answer , this code was not working because I was using API  23 and in AndroidManifest I had to add  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> in order that the code work

Answer (score 0):

when the AndroidSystem communicate your broadcast reciever nd run the onRecieve interface you should call startActivity method in onRecieve and start the WifiActivity  and get the scan results and pass it to ListView by calling setAdapter.
This works :)